# How might I change a publishing site to use Structured Current Navigation instead of Metadata Navigation using C# CSOM?

Tags: navigation, publishing-site, csom

I have come across many resources regarding how to add pages to navigation and how to change navigation settings but have not yet seen anything on how to go from Metadata Navigation to Structure Navigation for the Current Navigation  (left side nav) on a Publishing Site using CSOM.  Has anyone run across resources that describe how to accomplish this?  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I spoke a moment too soon.  I feel a bit sheepish but I had been searching for a couple hours with no luck!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124620/sharepoint2013-site-csom-update-navigation-settings

`var publishingWeb  = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(this.CC, subWeb);`

```
                // WebNavigationSettings
                var webNavigationSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(this.CC, subWeb);
                webNavigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;
                webNavigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;


                subWeb.Update();
                webNavigationSettings.Update(tSession);

                CC.Load(subWeb, WEB_INCLUDES);

                // Apply the load
                CC.ExecuteQuery();
```